# PrimeFaces CommandLink in dynamic datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, commandlink

I have a breadcrumb and datatable
[image]

Number of columns is dynamic. (ie: On clicking "Header7" in breadcrumb, 7 header column plus one "More-Info" column is to be rendered).

I created data-table using [primefaces-datatable-columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)

My xhtml file is :

```
<p:dataTable id="dataMain" var="car" value="#{orgUnitBean.rows}">
    <p:columns value="#{orgUnitBean.columns}" var="column"
        columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{car[column.property]}" filterBy="#{car[column.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car[column.property]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Question:
how to add commandLink in "More-Info" column. (currently I am just displaying "id" of last "Header" entity in it. In image attached: 3 is id of unitL3 and 13 is id of Lnitu3. I want to replace it with commandLink which will invoke bean method and pass these id as parameter to it).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rendered attribute of a commandLink in combination with the colIndex. Put this in the column like this

```
<p:commandLink rendered="#{colIndex == 5}" ... />
```

Where 5 is the index of the more-info column. You can also do a string compare on the colum header if you want.

(This is a very basic jsf pattern btw)

Comment: thx for replying. I have done sth like that already, but it look more like workaround than exact way.

Comment: Nope, it is the 'exact' (normal) way